# Office 2003 activation on a Windows XP over the phone doesn't show up

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2003

I´m trying to activate a Microsoft Office 2003 on a Windows XP SP3 over the phone but when a click on "I want to activate the software by telephone" nothing happens. I can't activate it over the internet because the PC isn't connected to it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Neither of these software suites are supported by Microsoft any more.

Comment: Read this [End of Office 2003 Telephone Activation](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-office_install/end-of-office-2003-telephone-activation/73fbc14c-ef12-4db5-81f6-9cc379b98794)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online activation should work.
If possible, try to connect it to the internet using a router with natting.

**But: Configure Windows XP firewall before connecting it to the internet**

To prevent any other accesses to the internet you should disable any outgoing connections to the internet using the Windows XP firewall. Then configure a rule to allow only the access to the microsoft server.